# bulk insert datetime data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to bulk insert some datetime values in this format:

31/12/2005 00:00:00

using something like this:

```
create table Seed
(
    StartDate datetime not null
)
BULK INSERT Seed
FROM 'd:\dump\Seed.txt' 
WITH 
( 
    firstrow=2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

But I get this:

Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row

I know how to define a codepage but which? Is there a simple solution?

Thanks.

Christian

Comment: Unless that's a typo in your question, 32/12/2005 is not a valid date, hence the type mismatch.

Comment: Thanks. sorry Joe edited it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the default language for the user logged in to the SQL instance while running this T-SQL?  The date format you specified 31/12/2005 00:00:00 looks to be British and perhaps your default language is US_English.

Try running this T-SQL to determine your current language:

```
SELECT @@language, @@langid
```

If it's US_English, then your date format should be mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss

To keep your example alive, try changing your default language for the current user by doing the following:

```
--Get the current language setting for connected user
SELECT @@LANGUAGE,@@LANGID

--Get information about all languages
EXEC sys.sp_helplanguage

--Get the name of the current user
DECLARE @sysuser NVARCHAR(30)

SET @sysuser = SYSTEM_USER

PRINT @sysuser
EXEC sp_defaultlanguage @sysuser, 'british' --satisfying your example date
```

After you have changed the default language, reconnect your query window and you should be now utilizing the new default language.

To get back to the previous language setting, just `EXEC sp_defaultlanguage` again with the language setting you previously had.

Hopefully that works!

Comment: Thanks this look interesting - yes my language is/was us_english

Comment: I don't think this will change the behavior of a BULK INSERT.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server is not going to convert the DD/MM/YYYY date format correctly. You'll need to either reformat your input file as MM/DD/YYYY or insert into a char/varchar datatype and then manipulate the string into the correct format for another datetime column. For example:

```
create table TempSeed
(
    StartDate varchar(50) not null
)

BULK INSERT TempSeed
FROM 'd:\dump\Seed.txt' 
WITH 
( 
    firstrow=2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

create table Seed
(
    StartDate datetime not null
)

insert into Seed
    (StartDate)
    select CAST(substring(ts.StartDate,4,3) + stuff(ts.StartDate,4,3,'') as datetime)
        from TempSeed ts
```

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. I think I will format things in the original file to avoid all this. Shame that sql server cannot cope with non US dates ...